# GFCI keeps tripping

Tags: gfci

I have a virtually new home, remodeled after hurricane, new outlets everywhere.  After a little more than a year, the GFCI keeps tripping. No new items plugged in, not doing anything different than I have been over the past year. Now, every day the outlet in my bathroom trips.  Seems like it happens overnight, because I have to reset every morning when I use my hair dryer... same hair dryer I’ve ha$ for a year. Hubby has tested it and it seems to be working ok.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Are there other outlets hooked up to the GFCI outlet in your bathroom that could be causing the problem?

Comment: What all loses power when you or hubby hit TEST on the GFCI?

Comment: I agree, it could be other loads. But we can start eliminating.  Move the hair dryer into the kitchen and leave it plugged into a kitchen receptacle for a couple of days.  Does it trip the GFCI there?

Answer (score 1):

This is in response to your questions and the comments made so far. What everyone is trying to do is to isolate and identify the problem which is the crux of all trouble shooting.

First you need to isolate the circuit. Find out which breaker your device is on and also identify any other devices, outlets or light fixtures are on the circuit. Then unplug any device that is attached to the circuit and turn off all lights. Look for ancillary equipment such as transformers for door bells etc. and make sure they are disconnected also. You are trying to identify any object that may be tripping the GFCI especially any device that may becoming on at night. such as a time clock or motion sensor.

Pay attention to Harper's comment this is a good way to find out if any equipment you have plugged in is actually the problem.

If you want to check to see if the GFCI is bad, the only method I feel I can rely on requires a Solenoid Voltage Tester commonly referred to as a WIGGY or Wiggens (nick name for the inventor). Problem is it was manufactured by *Square D* and is no longer available. I know *Ideal* and other manufactures still make them but they have become rather pricey. Regardless, if you put the probe into the small slot in the receptacle (hot) and put the other probe in the larger slot (neutral) you should get a reading. If you move the probe from the neutral to the U shaped slot (ground) the GFCI should trip. You can also use an outlet tester with a GFCI test on it, but most would agree that it is not considered all that reliable.

Now if you have tested the devices and checked the GFCI then you have isolated the problem to the circuit itself. At this point you have to go through and examine ever opening in the circuit and find the problem. I would start by finding areas that are subject to moister being present especially around splices and connections. This can cause enough voltage leakage to trip the GFCI.

Tracking down a problem in the circuit can be a long and tedious process and at that point some homeowners will elect to bring in a qualified and experienced service electrician to take care of the problem, rather than go through it themselves.

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: ^^^ this is excellent and detailed advice. Having said that, though, GFCIs go bad all the time. If you're comfortable changing a receptacle, just get a new one and see what happens. You have decent odds of fixing it outright. (Hint: note the wiring of the one you pull out. Line and load terminals matter, and aren't universally located.)

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate - Or you could just change out the GFCI and see if that works first. Absolutely.